# Credit card payment in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, paypal, credit-card

I am developing a mobile app using Xamarin. 
My main target will be Android devices, but i want to be able to extend to IOS. 
I want to set up a "marketplace", where you can buy currency, used to buy items in the app. The user should be able to pay with their credit card.

Do any of you have experience with implementing credit-card payment in Xamarin?
I have been looking at the paypal SDK, but i am not sure if it is the right one to go with, so if you have hands-on experience, i would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking down the route of using the relevant "app stores" for doing your payments. Particularly on the Apple side, they tend to reject payment methods external to their own. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/in-app_purchasing/

There is a recent article here regarding the setup of in-app purchasing on Android and IOS.
https://blog.xamarin.com/integrating-in-app-purchases-in-mobile-apps/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that is very good to know. So its only the large developers that get to do payment around the app stores?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Stripe](https://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe) and see if does what you are looking for. It does have Apple Pay support, and has been fairly easy to use in past app projects for credit card payments.

Comment: You are right, Stripe is very competative with its prices and services! As i see it, you would get a lot more for your money there!